# Name Data does not import into Rstudio as intended

Tags: r, csv, rstudio, data-import

I'm currently trying to import a data set of names into RStudio. I have the data saved as a `.csv` file with 276 rows. In Microsoft Excel it looks like this:

[image]

When I try to import into RStudio, (from Text), it gives me this window:

[image]

Then, when trying to import the data I receive the following error:

> "Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
>     duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed"

The data appears in RStudio like this:

[image]

If a person has 3 names (a few do) they appear on the next line by themselves. Why is my data doing this? I want both first and last names to be in the same column with the heading "person".

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: you can try `file <- read.csv('C:/path/your_file.csv', row.names = FALSE)`

Comment: I've never imported a file this way, but I think you just need to change the value in `Separator` to comma, not whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use RStudio's `Import Data > From Text` you need to set `Row names` to "Use numbers" and `Separator` to "Semicolon".

`Row names` set to "Automatic" is what is causing the error you're referencing.  By being set to "Automatic", RStudio is importing what it interprets as the first column as row labels for the data frame.  In this case, RStudio is trying to use first names as the row labels for your data (more on why this is happening below).  This is an issue because your data contains multiple individuals with the same first name.  Put another way, a data frame cannot have two row `1`'s therefore it cannot have two row `John`'s.

`Separator` set to "Whitespace" is splitting your names where ever there is white space in the data; the spaces between names count as white space. Setting `Separator` to "Semicolon" ensures full names are not split.

Note: using "Comma" can split names that have a suffix (such as "Josh Smith, Jr." which would be separated to be "John Smith" and "Jr.").

Alternatively, you can use the `read.csv()` function like this:

```
df <- read.csv("starpower.csv", row.names = FALSE, sep = ";")
```

The above line of code will import your `.csv` file located at path `starpower.csv`, it tells RStudio your data does not have row labels (therefore RStudio will default to numbering each row itself), and it changes the default way of reading your data from entries in a row being separated by commas (`,`) to semicolons (`;`).  Again, semicolons are likely a better separator for you to use since your data is a single column that may contain commas.

Note: if your data contains multiple columns you must set `Seperator` when using RStudio's `Import Data` tool and `sep =` when using the `read.csv()` function to the symbol that is used to separate rows in your data.  The default for `.csv` files is commas (`,`).

I hope this helps!